# How to install multiple themes all at the same time in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: themes

I have downloaded the theme files and I am trying to install them one at a time.

Is there any way to install all of them at the same time?

Comment: This is similar to installing themes in previous ubuntu versions check the answer

Comment: @shellter Oh my bad i will move the question where is the flag link

Comment: @shellter ya requested the moderator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install multiple themes
make a folder `.themes` in your `home` directory
copy all `theme folders` to this directory

```
mkdir ~/.themes
```

Then open `Unity Tweak Tool` and select `themes` and you will see all the themes there

Similarly same for installing `fonts` and `icon themes` too

```
mkdir ~/.fonts
```

and copy all the fonts

```
mkdir ~/.icons
```

and copy all the icon themes

**warning:**
icon themes should be in `.icons`

If the themes are of `.deb` files just do the following steps
make new folder

```
mkdir newfolder
```

you can give any name you like but make sure that it contains only your theme files
next change directory to that new folder

```
cd 'your folder path'
```

next run the flllowing script,be sure you are in the new directory you have created and it contains only `.deb` theme files

```
for theme in *;do sudo dpkg -i $theme;done
```

Here `dpkg` means `debian package`

Comment: @muru thanks for editing now it looks clean and simple